# Script to create a DE in MC automation studio enterprise edition

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, soap-api, automationstudio

I am using this script to create a Data Extension in automation studio.
I checked my code on a landing page and the statuscode is 200. Whene running it on automation studio as a script it returns an error.
Is it even possible to create a DE automatically on an entreprise edition?

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1");

// Marketing Cloud API credentials
var clientId = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
var clientSecret = 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET';
var subdomain = 'YOUR_SUBDOMAIN';
var accountId = 'YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID';
var categoryID = 'YOUR_CATEGORY_ID';

// Authenticate to Marketing Cloud API
var authEndpoint = 'https://' + subdomain + '.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token';
var authPayload = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": clientId,
    "client_secret": clientSecret,
    "account_id": accountId
};
var authResponse = HTTP.Post(authEndpoint, 'application/json', Stringify(authPayload));
var authToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(authResponse.Response[0]).access_token;

// Create Data Extension
var deEndpoint = 'https://' + subdomain + '.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx';
var dePayload = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">' +
        '<soap:Header>' +
            '<fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">' + authToken + '</fueloauth>' +
        '</soap:Header>' +
        '<soap:Body>' +
            '<CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">' +
                '<Objects xsi:type="DataExtension">' +
                    '<Name>YOUR_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME</Name>' +
                    '<CustomerKey>YOUR_DATA_EXTENSION_KEY</CustomerKey>' +
                    '<CategoryID>' + categoryID + '</CategoryID>' +
                    '<Fields>' +
                        '<Field>' +
                            '<Name>SubscriberKey</Name>' +
                            '<FieldType>Text</FieldType>' +
                            '<MaxLength>254</MaxLength>' +
                            '<IsRequired>true</IsRequired>' +
                            '<IsPrimaryKey>true</IsPrimaryKey>' +
                        '</Field>' +
                        '<Field>' +
                            '<Name>EmailAddress</Name>' +
                            '<FieldType>EmailAddress</FieldType>' +
                            '<IsRequired>true</IsRequired>' +
                            '<MaxLength>254</MaxLength>' +
                        '</Field>' +
                        '<Field>' +
                            '<Name>CategoryID</Name>' +
                            '<FieldType>Number</FieldType>' +
                            '<IsRequired>true</IsRequired>' +
                        '</Field>' +
                    '</Fields>' +
                '</Objects>' +
            '</CreateRequest>' +
        '</soap:Body>' +
    '</soap:Envelope>';
var deResponse = HTTP.Post(deEndpoint, 'text/xml', dePayload, ["Content-Type"], ["text/xml"], null, null, null);

// Log response
if (deResponse.StatusCode == 200) {
    Write("Data Extension created successfully.");
} else {
    Write("Error creating Data Extension: " + Stringify(deResponse.Response[0]));
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run it in Marketing Cloud it's better to use WSProxy - in the back-end is still SOAP API but it's much easier to write the code. This code works for me in both Script activity in Automation Studio and Cloud Page:

```
<script runat="server">
  var categoryId = "YOUR_CATEGORY_ID"; /* DE Folder ID */
  var fields = [
                {
                 "Name": "SubscriberKey",
                 "FieldType": "Text",
                 "MaxLength": 254,
                 "IsRequired": true,
                 "IsPrimaryKey": true
                },
                {
                 "Name": "EmailAddress",
                 "FieldType": "EmailAddress",
                 "MaxLength": 254,
                 "IsRequired": true
                },
                {
                 "Name": "CategoryID",
                 "FieldType": "Number",
                 "IsRequired": true
                }
               ];
  var config = {
                "CustomerKey": "YOUR_DE_EXTERNAL_KEY",
                "Name": "YOUR_DE_NAME",
                "CategoryID": categoryId,
                "Fields": fields
               };
  try {
       var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
       var result = api.createItem("DataExtension", config);
  } catch(e) {}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this insight